# C#, combox, switch int.Parse results in error

Tags: c#, parsing, combobox, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a simple program with a combobox. but no choises are available in the dropdown menu when the program is runned. Furthermore i think the issue starts while i try to parse an integer to text in the beginning of the program. However I'm not yet skilled enough to fix this :( . In the following is my code and the errors from visual studio:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testerv1._01
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnBuyEU_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = int.Parse(cbxBuyEU.Text);
        int price = 0;
        switch (n)
        {
            case 1:
                price += 25;
                break;
            case 2:
                price += 25;
                goto case 1;
            case 3:
                price += 50;
                goto case 1;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("you made a wrong choice..");
                break;
        }
        if (price != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("deposit "+ price +"");
        }
        MessageBox.Show("thank you and good buy");

    }
}
}
```

Here is the errors:

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Int32.Parse(String s)
   at testerv1._01.Form1.btnBuyEU_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\jjj\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\testerv1.01\testerv1.01    \Form1.cs:line 21
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at testerv1._01.Program.Main() in C:\Documents and Settings\jjj\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\testerv1.01\testerv1.01\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: How does the string look? That is a parsing error in `int n = int.Parse(cbxBuyEU.Text);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear, the input string value is invalid.

You should use `TryParse` to check if the value is valid. `Parse` assumes the parameter is a valid integer, which is not true in your case.

```
int outValue;
if (int.TryParse(cbxBuyEU.Text, out outValue))
{
    // Then the value is OK and outValue contains the parsed value
}
```

Comment: Hi Ken2k Thanks!

Ups. posted the comment to soon. 

As you may have guessed, I'm a bit new in programming. However it now works after your help :). 

here is what i put in instead of my original code:

`code`            int n;
            int.TryParse(cbxBuyEU.Text, out n);
            int price = 0;
            switch (n)
            {
                case 1:....

Furthermore I also needed to add in the combobox tasks "1, 2, 3" in the form view before it worked. I'm not sure if this was the most ideal solution but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = Convert.ToInt32(cbxBuyEU.Text)
```